# Can't Write To TextBox + Can't use Checkbox as a string variable

Tags: string, hyperlink, textbox, vb.net

Problem 1: Can't Use a CheckBox as a String Variable

```
Dim link As String = CheckBox1.Checked
```

Problem 2: Can't figure out how to write the results of my code to my textbox:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If (Not RawPaste.Text = Nothing) Then
        Dim r As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(link)
        r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36"
        r.KeepAlive = True
        Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()
        Dim src As String = New StreamReader(re.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
        Dim rows As String() = GetBetweenAll(src, "<tr>", "</tr>")
        Dim tds As New List(Of String)
        Dim dones As New List(Of String)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each s As String In rows
            If (Not s = rows(0) And s.Contains("<td>") And s.Contains("</td>")) Then
                Dim td As String() = GetBetweenAll(s, "<td>", "</td>")
                Dim ip As String = td(0)
                Dim port As String = td(1)
                dones.Add(ip & ":" & port)

                sb.Append(ip & ":" & port)   ' or dones.Count-1, but i dont
                ' know what it is List? Array?
            End If
        Next
        RawPaste.Text = sb.ToString
        Progress.Value = 100
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1) of course not: strings are text and checkboxes are objects...you probably want this:

```
Dim link As String = CheckBox1.Text
```

if you were really after the checkstate, set it in a IF block, or try

```
Dim link As String = CheckBox1.Checked.ToString   ' will be 'True' or 'False'
```

Final Edit:  With the poorly named `CheckBox1` now revealed to be a CheckedLISTBOX, you have to get the text from the one selected, if there is one:

```
Dim link as string
If CheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Count THen       ' check for at least one checked
   link = CheckedListBox.CheckedItems(0).ToString
End if
```

2) try this:

```
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(RawPaste.Text)
        For Each s As String In dones
            sw.WriteLine(s) //<- I want to replace that so it writes to a textbox
            TextBoxToWriteTo.Text &= s
        Next
    End Using
```

I am not sure of the relationship between RawPaste and dones, but that loop should be able to be optomized:

EDIT:

YOu dont need a stream writer at all, just append the text as you process:

```
    Dim sb as New StringBuilder
    For Each s As String In rows
        If (Not s = rows(0) And s.Contains("<td>") And s.Contains("</td>")) Then
            Dim td As String() = GetBetweenAll(s, "<td>", "</td>")
            Dim ip As String = td(0)
            Dim port As String = td(1)
            dones.Add(ip & ":" & port)

            sb.Append (ip & ":" & port)   ' or dones.Count-1, but i dont
                                  ' know what it is List? Array?
        End If
    Next

    RawPaste.Text = sb.ToString
```

...and if that was the whole point of dones - to accumulate for the textbox, it is not needed anymore

Comment: The check box contains links and the program breaks when using also: Error 1 'TextBoxToWriteTo' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level I should probably tell you that RawPaste is the name of my textbox

Comment: `TextBoxToWriteTo` is of course a dummy variable, you are supposed to replace with the real one.  so you just want to replicate the text in `RawPaste` X number of times?  REALLY do not need streamwriter for that!

Comment: I want to rephrase my question for #1 it's a check list for website to go and RIP certain content from. Link = the link that it will go to. I want the check box to work so people can select certain links for certain categories. I tried CheckBox1.Checked.ToString before coming here and it gives the error "Error 1 'Checked' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox'."

Comment: Also It's a list not an array

Comment: so, `CheckBox1` is a checkedlistbox???? that would be nice to know - look at the title you wrote...  what do you need `link` to be, the text of the currently checked item or what?  since it is a `CheckedLISTBOX` there can be more than 1 - what then?

Comment: I fixed everything except for my checklist thing. Oh but my Raw Paste is only showing the last line of data

Comment: Actually just fixed raw paste but have to make it auto format

Comment: see my edit for the CheckedLISTBOX,  for multiple lines, set the textbox to be multiline, but also make sure that there are more than 1 row being processed.

Comment: "Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda." On the If Statement "Declaration Expected" <- on link = CheckBox1.CheckedItems(0).ToString

Comment: the `DIM` part can go where the old line was, the rest is CODE and has to be inside a SUB, FUNCTION or PROPERTY.  put it just before you go to use `link` (I have ZERO context here, you only showed 1 line for this).  If it is not in the form containing the CheckedLISTBox, you will also need a form reference.

Comment: It works but not how it's supposed to. Assume Dim link As String = "a URL here" how would I do multiple URLS?

Comment: @user3015445 use a loop. look up the properties for the CheckedListBox (as easy as using the VS Object Browser), especially CheckedIndices and CheckedItems and process the checked ones in a loop.  `It works...` then you should check the checkmark so this falls off the unanswered list and gain some rep for yourself

Comment: ACtually had a better idea, how would i make Dim r As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(CheckBox) accept a checkbox?

Comment: we are out of room here.  that should be a new question after you give it a try yourself.  welcome to SO!

Comment: You got skype by chance?